# What does the command String imageName( "../data/HappyFish.jpg" ); do?

Tags: opencv

I am a total beginner in OpenCV. I was learning a program to load and display an image where the below statement is used.
String imageName( "../data/HappyFish.jpg" ); //by default
what does this statement do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement is the folder directory of the image file HappyFish.jpg in the OpenCV example Load and Display an Image. Simply it is used with imread to indicate the location where our image file is located.

```
    image = imread( imageName, IMREAD_COLOR ); // Read the file
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Your welcome, remember to accept the answer to your question.